# Error with linux-system76 while trying to install packages in Pop!_OS iso using Cubic

Tags: kernel, package-management, iso, distributions

My laptop does not allow disabling RAID, so it is incompatible with most Linux distributions. One distribution that has no problem with RAID is *EndlessOS*, so what I have been doing for the past years is replacing the kernel of my desired distribution with the kernel from *EndlessOS*. This has worked perfectly in the past with *Ubuntu* and *Kubuntu*. However, when trying to do the same with *Pop!_OS*, I am having problems. I will summarise below:

- I use cubic to modify the `.iso` of the chosen distribution prior to installation
- The steps I use to do this are:

  1. Open Cubic and choose the ISO file to modify
  2. Navigate to the virtual console environment and execute these commands:

     ```
     curl -sS https://deb.endlessos.org/keys/eos-pub-archive-key.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/endlessOS.gpg

     cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/endlessOS.pref << EOF
     Package: *
     Pin: origin "deb.endlessos.org"
     Pin-Priority: 1

     Package: linux-headers-generic
     Pin: origin "deb.endlessos.org"
     Pin-Priority: 1000

     Package: linux-image-generic
     Pin: origin "deb.endlessos.org"
     Pin-Priority: 1000
     EOF

     echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://deb.endlessos.org/debian master endless" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/endlessOS.list
     ```
  3. At this point, to avoid `linux-headers-6.1.0-14-generic : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable` error in the next step, I have to manually install `libssl1.1`:

     ```
     echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list
     apt-get update
     apt-get install libssl1.1
     rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list
     ```
  4. I run this to install the new kernel

     ```
     apt update
     apt install linux-headers-generic/master linux-image-generic/master
     ```
- The installation step is where I have the error that I have not been able to fix. I have not found anything of help on the internet so far either:

  ```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  pop-desktop : Depends: linux-system76 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
  ```
- When I try to install the package manually (I also ran `apt upgrade`), I get this:

  ```
  root@cubic:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt install linux-system76
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  linux-system76 is already the newest version (6.2.6.76060206.202303130630~1681329778~22.04~d824cd4).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  root@cubic:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt install pop-desktop
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  pop-desktop is already the newest version (1.6.0~1681329444~22.04~7d38466).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  ```